# jQuery slide changes the width when slides

Tags: jquery, css, html, uislider

The code works fine.
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyWTL/3/)

The only problem is that it changes its width when slides (when press "click here"). Seems like it cuts the width that corresponds to 100px of the margin-left in #slider.

Why does it "jump" and how to fix it? Is there anything wrong with the code?

What is in there: a slider of the centered div that has a content and a sticky footer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it fits your needs, but you can simply set :

**CSS**

```
...

.slider{

    ...

    bottom:0px;

    ...

}
```

and then simply use jQuery .slideToggle() which will handle the open/closed statuses and is much more smooth:

**JS**

```
$("#slide-link").click(function (){

    $('#slider').slideToggle();

});
```

here's a [sample jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyWTL/5/)

**EDIT 1**

Updated this so that #slide-link toggles too with #slider.

Basically what we do is animate it based on whether #slider is hidden or not:

```
if(!$('#slider').is(':hidden')){

    $(this).animate({

        top: $('#global-container').height()-23

    },500)

 }else{

    $(this).animate({

        top: '0px'

    },500) 

 }
```

- [JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vyWTL/10/)

**EDIT 2**

Here's another more hacky way for not having to deal with that if(#slider is hidden) thus writing the .animate function only once.

Basically $('#slider').is(':hidden') is a boolean and in JS booleans are equivalent to 0/1 values where false = 0 and true = 1, thus you can write:

```
var hid = $('#slider').is(':hidden')

$(this).animate({

    top: (1-hid)*(contHeight)

 },500)
```

Where contHeight is the #global-container height - #slide-link height.

- [JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vyWTL/12/)

**EDIT 3 Scroll Issue**

If I got your problem in comment right, when you fill up the content part with allot of words id doesn't scroll, but the content panel seems to fill the wole #slider and continue out the page without being able to scroll it.

This is due to the fact .content has not a fixed height, this is because we know the footer is 70px high, and simply we want the .content to fill up all the space left inside the #slider, but this way .content doesn't have a "fixed value" i.e. inside its css there's no definition for its height. So what we need to do is dynamically tell him how hight it has to be just the way we do it with #slide, so add in the JS

```
$('.content').height(contHeight-70)
```

this way you can now add:

```
overflow:hidden; //this is to prevent orizontal scroll
overflow-y:scroll; // this enables vertical scroll
```

Hope I got this right.

- [JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vyWTL/15/)

Comment: I see thought what you need is the #slide-link bar to get toggled too... working on it!

Comment: here's also a more hacky but code-plan solution based on the fact that javascript interprets false as 0 and true as 1 so you can use the #slider auto toggling to animate the #slide-link top to #container.height()-23 *(1 - #slider.is(':hidden')) like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vyWTL/12/

Comment: I've just recovered @ http://jsfiddle.net/vyWTL/12/ that if content has a lot of text, it can't be scrolled down (no scrolls because of #slider position:absolute. Should I open another topic for this question separately?

Comment: you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/vyWTL/14/ ... please define "can't be scrolled down"

Comment: Onheiron, sorry, I meant for the whole page:(, not for the content... I'm sorry I didn't explain it... Footer is sticked on the bottom, if not enough text... But, if a lot of text, then there is no scroll bar on the browser, and that's the problem... Should I start a new topic? Thank you anyway. You helped me a lot.

Comment: oh, ok... then please start a new question, if you want to tag me in a comment there I'll try to help.

Comment: Seems like I've just recovered the problem a second ago, #global-container overflow:hidden; was a problem. Just removed it. Hope it works. Thank you very much.... Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the negative margin on #slider. For some reason it won't draw properly on animation.

Here's a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/vyWTL/8/

It keeps `margin-left` at 0px, and uses jquery to calculate what `left` should be, given the width of the container. Since that's dynamic and can change when the viewport width is adjusted, I put it in a function call that is called on pageload and on window resize.

Comment: Sorry I can't choose both asnwers as best. The other one was chosen as I like that code better (seems like less style movements are done after the page loads).

Answer (score -1):

```
.ui-effects-wrapper{  overflow-x: visible !important;  width: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!